# Monostable IC 555 with 12 volts output voltage

Tags: 555

i know that in the 555 IC you can feed it using 5 volts to 15 volts, i need a Monostable circuit using a 555 with output voltage, i can use a transistor in the output, does anyone has a diagram like this??, anyhelp is appreciated, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet for the 555 has the circuit. No need for transistor unless you are driving high current outputs.

Fairchild Semiconductor 555 datasheet is here:
https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM555.pdf

Comment: Yes, but which one? Given the question, he is probably confused enough looking at that.

Comment: On page 4 there is a circuit diagram under the heading 'Monostable Operation'. I hope that it will be informative and get the OP to look at the data sheet when using a chip. As a reference source for chip usage, data sheets should be checked first, even if they might look a bit intimidating.